# Kubuntu and LibreOffice keyboard shortcuts

Tags: keyboard, kubuntu, shortcut-keys, kde, libreoffice

I am running Kubuntu 21.04 and LibreOffice v7.0.6 (latest stable release) and some keyboard shortcuts work while others don't. I am using normal US keyboard. For example,

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>[</kbd> -- doesn't
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>]</kbd> -- doesn't
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd> -- does

I am able to assign the above shortcuts for example to KDE apps and they work, just not in LibreOffice. I upgraded to the latest version of Plasma, 5.22 and the issue persists.

When the same version of LO is running under GNOME the shortcuts work just fine.

I have been using these shortcuts under Windows for a long time and I am loath to change them. Muscle memory and all that...

Any ideas?